# Web service not working after upgrading from CF8 to CF10

Tags: soap, coldfusion, wsdl

I have an intranet application that makes a post to `localhost/site/maint/dbLibrary.cfc?wsdl` and the service would then respond with a result. However since upgrading from CF8 to CF10 when making a post to the wsdl firebug shows the request just hanging there with no error or response. It just hangs out forever, no errors. So how do I fix this? Is there a setting or permission in the administrator or something?

Help is very much appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: How about some code? Also, describe the provider and consumer of the service. Is it CF on both ends? You may also want to enable the server monitor in the CF admin and see what it's picking up.

Comment: +1 on the server monitor. If that doesn't give you what you need, use VisualVM or jStack to get a thread dump whilst the server is hung: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10909946/826714 then post the thread dump here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay looks like its a bug with CF10. Apparently the new update 3 will fix it when it gets rolled back out. The release mentions the following bug fix:

> "ColdFusion server is non-responsive when receiving a POST request
>   with an XML body for a Web Service."